# Select application after click clone in Bitbucket/Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

We have one repository which has 36 branches in the remote end. For some reason, I cloned one branch to my c:\drive. Then I realized that it might be incorrect. I may need to clone the entire repository rather than just one branch.

So I deleted all local respective folders and cloned the repository again. But it asked me to pick up an application.

What is wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I can't clone a branch before clone a repository. I cloned a repository then it looks fine.